# HTTP Post method using curl to post data to localhost failed

Tags: java, google-app-engine, curl, jdo, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm trying to use HTTP GET method using:

```
curl http://localhost:8888/_ah/api/birra/v1/beer
```

it's returning me the current list like which is normal and expected:

```
{
  "items" : [ {
    "id" : "1",
    "beerName" : "Bud"
  }, {
    "id" : "2",
    "beerName" : "Steve"
  }, {
    "id" : "3",
    "beerName" : "Ankur"
  } ]
}
```

But when i'm doing HTTP POST like this:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept:application/json" -d "{\"beerName\": \"asdf\"}" http://localhost:8888/_ah/api/birra/v1/beer
```

it's giving me error as:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "message" : "javax.jdo.JDOFatalInternalException: The key value passed to construct a SingleFieldIdentity of type \"class javax.jdo.identity.LongIdentity\" for class \"class com.samples.Beer\" is null.\nNestedThrowables:\norg.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusException: The key value passed to construct a SingleFieldIdentity of type \"class javax.jdo.identity.LongIdentity\" for class \"class com.samples.Beer\" is null.",
    "code" : 503,
    "errors" : [ {
      "domain" : "global",
      "reason" : "backendError",
      "message" : "javax.jdo.JDOFatalInternalException: The key value passed to construct a SingleFieldIdentity of type \"class javax.jdo.identity.LongIdentity\" for class \"class com.samples.Beer\" is null.\nNestedThrowables:\norg.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusException: The key value passed to construct a SingleFieldIdentity of type \"class javax.jdo.identity.LongIdentity\" for class \"class com.samples.Beer\" is null."
    } ]
  }
}
```

I'm currently working on Google Cloud Endpoints sample provided on:
[Cloud Endpoint by Google Developers](http://ido-green.appspot.com/CloudEndpoints/CloudEndpointsWebBlogPost.html)

I'm using Eclipse IDE with server localhost running on Jetty.

Any solutions?

Comment: Isn't `id` needed in the input JSON?

Comment: No, i'm using 'beerName' as key in my code and so i'm passing a value as 'asdf' to it. 
Where do you use id? 
Also, please take a look at code in the link i provided, its the same thing that's told in tutorial.

Comment: Just a wild guess.. The exception contains `javax.jdo.identity.LongIdentity`. I think `LongIdentity` means that it must be something pertaining to the `id` as it must be a Java `long` value

Comment: Are you sure that a new `Beer` object will get constructed even without providing `id`? Also, as far as I understand the code in your link, I think `id` is the key and not `beerName`. If you see the `getBeer` service endpoint, it is accepting `id` and not `beerName`

Comment: No, in getBeer(), the 'id' that it is taking is to retrieve data from server.
if we do this: curl localhost:8888/_ah/api/birra/v1/beer/1
it will return the entity with 'id' = '1'

Please take a look into insertBeer(), i'm getting error only while doing HTTP POST. HTTP GET is working just fine.

Comment: What I mean is that since `getBeer()` is getting a `Beer` object based on `id`, `id` is the identifier of a `Beer` object and not `beerName`

Answer (score 5):

Use double quote instead of single. This type of errors occur when you are running from windows. That's why it says `couldn't resolve host`.

```
curl  -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"beerName\": \"bud\"}" http://localhost:8888/_ah/api/birra/v1/beer
```

Comment: `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept:application/json" -d "{\"beerName\": \"asdf\"}" http://localhost:8888/_ah/api/birra/v1/beer`



`{
  "error" : {
"message" : "javax.jdo.JDOFatalInternalException: The key value passed to construct a SingleFieldIdentity of type \"class javax.jdo.identity.LongIdentity\" for class \"class com.samples.Beer\" is null.\nNestedThrowables:\norg.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusException: The key value passed to construct a SingleFieldIdentity of type \"class javax.jdo.identity.LongIdentity\" for class \"class com.samples.Beer\" is null."`

Comment: I used this command so host couldn't be resolved error is gone, but main error is still coming.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user3275261 its the problem from the server side. May be you parsed the json wrongfully and some fields got null, just guessing.